# Facebook authentication with Popup

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am trying to achieve a Facebook login in android with the native pop-up that asks for permission (with the profile image etc.)
I have followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) and am able to log into facebook, but the app just flashes for a short moment, loads, and then finishes the login and goes to the next screen. There is no review of the Account Information (or a selection which account I would like to use) like with google login.

How can I achieve this as a popup? :

[image]

Comment: _“or a selection which account i would like to use”_ - why should there be ... you are only allowed to have one personal Facebook account in the first place; and unlike desktop computers or laptops, Android devices are usually not passed around between different users.

Comment: regardless, i feel like the prompt to ask is good user design and would like to do it. Even if its not a selection but just the review